# Como acessar a Porta Serial de um computador em Java?

Tags: java, porta-serial

Como faço para acessar/controlar uma Porta Serial através de Java? Atualmente consegui acessar em C++, porém, em Java não sei como fazer. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe a biblioteca jSSC que fornece comunicação com a porta serial
https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/

Adicione a dependência no seu pom.xml, se não usar o maven baixe a biblioteca e coloque no classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
    <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Classe de Teste

```
public class SerialTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

     try {
            System.out.println("Port opened: " + serialPort.openPort());
            System.out.println("Params setted: " + serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0));
            System.out.println("\"Hello World!!!\" successfully writen to port: " + serialPort.writeBytes("Hello World!!!".getBytes()));
            System.out.println("Port closed: " + serialPort.closePort());
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
}
```

}

[image: exemplo]

Peguei esse exemplo no site da API

Comment: Não seria melhor adicionar um comentário?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Coloquei o exemplo agora

Comment: Show de bola!   @adelmo00

Comment: Muito bom este exemplo @adelmo00, mutio obrigado pela ajuda!